# How do I serialize the Polyline class?

Tags: android, gson, android-maps-v2

Is there some easy way to serialize an `ArrayList<Polyline>`? ([Polyline](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html) is a class from com.google.android.gms.maps.model. In the snippet below, the array list is called polylines2)

I tried using gson.toJson but I get a StackOverflow error.

[I haven't done Android or Java development in over 3 years, so apologies if this is obvious.]

```
String polylinesSerialized = "";
polylinesSerialized = gson.toJson(polylines2);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502398/serialize-or-save-polylineoptions-in-android check this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to send the polyline over to a different part of the app, here are some ideas:

- Implement `Serializable`or `Parcelable` on the a class that holds the polyline and pass it through Intens.
- Pass an array of points that you use to reconstruct the polyline again.
- Use local persistence
- Keep some cache in memory
- Attach them to an event of a bus. eg.: [greendroid](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)